# DatabaseException: Can´t convert object of type java.lang.String to type

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, adapter

Muy buenas! Comunidad! Les traigo un inconveniente mío, me podrían dar una mano? El problema radica en que al ejecutar la app y acceder a la activity principal, se detiene la aplicación.. he buscado varias soluciones pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Estoy seteando el adaptador al recycler.. pero al debug la app me doy cuenta que el error está en la línea 81:

> "AlquilerModel alquilerModel = snapshot.getValue(AlquilerModel.class)";

[image: Este es el Error]

Este es mi presenter principal:

```
public class PresenterPrincipal implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Context mContext;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private Dialog dialog;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private RecyclerAlquilerAdapter mAdapter;

    private EditText nombrePersona, apellidoPersona, direccion,ciudad;

    public PresenterPrincipal(Context mContext, FirebaseAuth mAuth, DatabaseReference mDatabase) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mAuth = mAuth;
        this.mDatabase = mDatabase;
    }

    public void WelcomeMessage() {

        mDatabase.child("Usuarios").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                UserModel userModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Bienvenido" + userModel.getNombre(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

    }

    public void CargarRecyclerView(final RecyclerView mRecycler){

        mDatabase.child("Usuarios").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Alquileres").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                ArrayList<AlquilerModel> arrayListAlquiler = new ArrayList<>();

                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    AlquilerModel alquilerModel = snapshot.getValue(AlquilerModel.class);

                    String nombrepersona = alquilerModel.getNombrePersona();
                    String apellidopersona = alquilerModel.getApellidoPersona();
                    String ciudad = alquilerModel.getCiudad();
                    alquilerModel.setNombrePersona(nombrepersona);
                    alquilerModel.setApellidoPersona(apellidopersona);
                    alquilerModel.setCiudad(ciudad);

                    arrayListAlquiler.add(alquilerModel);
                }

                mAdapter=new RecyclerAlquilerAdapter(mContext,arrayListAlquiler);
                mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void CargarAlquiler() {

        dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_row);
        nombrePersona = dialog.findViewById(R.id.EtxtNombrePersona);
        apellidoPersona = dialog.findViewById(R.id.EtxtApellidoPersona);
        direccion = dialog.findViewById(R.id.EtxtDireccion);
        ciudad = dialog.findViewById(R.id.EtxtCiudad);

        Button btnRegAlquiler = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnAddAlquiler);
        btnRegAlquiler.setOnClickListener(this);
        dialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnAddAlquiler:

                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Añadiendo Alquiler..");
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();

                String NombrePersona = nombrePersona.getText().toString().trim();
                String ApellidoPersona = apellidoPersona.getText().toString().trim();
                String Direccion = direccion.getText().toString().trim();
                String Ciudad = ciudad.getText().toString().trim();
                CargarAlquilerFirebase(NombrePersona, ApellidoPersona, Direccion, Ciudad);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void CargarAlquilerFirebase(String NombrePersona, String ApellidoPersona, String Direccion, String Ciudad) {

        Map<String, Object> alquiler = new HashMap<>();
        alquiler.put("NombrePersona", NombrePersona);
        alquiler.put("ApellidoPersona", ApellidoPersona);
        alquiler.put("Direccion", Direccion);
        alquiler.put("Ciudad", Ciudad);

        mDatabase.child("Usuarios").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Alquileres").updateChildren(alquiler).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Se cargo el alquiler correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error al cargar alquiler" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

- Este es mi Adaptador:

```
public class RecyclerAlquilerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAlquilerAdapter.AlquilerViewHolder>{

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<AlquilerModel> arrayListAlquileres;

    public RecyclerAlquilerAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<AlquilerModel> arrayListAlquileres) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.arrayListAlquileres = arrayListAlquileres;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AlquilerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.alquileres_row,viewGroup,false);

        return new AlquilerViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AlquilerViewHolder alquilerViewHolder, int position) {

        AlquilerModel alquilerModel = arrayListAlquileres.get(position);

        alquilerViewHolder.mNombrePersona.setText(alquilerModel.getNombrePersona());
        alquilerViewHolder.mApellidoPersona.setText(alquilerModel.getApellidoPersona());
        alquilerViewHolder.mCiudad.setText(alquilerModel.getCiudad());
        alquilerViewHolder.mImagenHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {                                                                        
        if(arrayListAlquileres.size()>0){
            return arrayListAlquileres.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public class AlquilerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView mNombrePersona,mApellidoPersona,mCiudad;
        ImageView mImagenHome;

        public AlquilerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);                                                          
            mNombrePersona = itemView.findViewById(R.id.NombreRow);                                    
            mApellidoPersona = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ApellidoRow);
            mCiudad = itemView.findViewById(R.id.CiudadRow);
            mImagenHome = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagenAlquilerRow);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(mContext,Vista_Alquiler_Detalles.class);
            mContext.startActivity(i);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: No puede convertir un atributo del tipo String a tú objecto, probablemente sea un formato Json String, puedes hacer un   System.out.println(stringProblemas) antes de asignarlo al objeto para verificar su valor

Answer (score 0):

Tu error está en el for. El evento onDataChange entrega un snapshot de un elemento, por lo que simplemente debes poner: `dataSnapshot.getValue(AlquilerModel.class)` ahí en tu código necesitas re-pensarlo para hacer lo que estás buscando, porque ese for te va a llevar por cada campo. Por ejemplo, si recibes un evento onDataChange, el snapshot que recibirás es (notación json):

```
{
  "id" : "abcdefg",
  "referencia" : "Alquiler por 2 días",
  "monto" : 125.34,
  ...
}
```

Entonces, solamente tendrías que invocar a `dataSnapshot.getValue(AlquilerModel.class)` y ahí no te genera error. Cuando pones el `for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())` lo que vas a recibir son los hijos, o sea, en cada iteración vas a recibir "abcdefg", "Alquiler por 2 días", 125.34 y así sucesivamente, y como la String no se puede convertir a AlquilerModel, te lanza la exception.

Te recomendaría que revises el tutorial oficial de google: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?hl=es#java_4 Ahí el link te va a llevar directo al ejemplo con un ValueEventListener.